# Endoscope for a pools plumbing

Tags: pool

Has anyone tried to use an endoscope for their pool plumbing? I bought one but it wont get very far into the pool lines without getting stuck. Ive tried using a plumbing snake by itself, but really it just does the same thing. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have 3 returns that are not working. I have in the past repaired kinked flex lines in the ground where I could dig them up, but now everything is under concrete. So I want to try and make sure its what I think it is, more kinked lines. If I could get the camera to go the whole length I could maybe find out where the kink is and have a chance at fixing it myself.

Comment: Is it getting snagged on a 90 degree bend?

Comment: Flex lines underground well you know what the problem is ether a 90 since these lines are pressure based and not drains that have sweeps. It’s that or crushed flex. Not much we can suggest other try going from the other side but you will hit the T or 90 and get stuck again even if not crushed.

Comment: Yup, tried that as well. I tried going into the return as well and just hit another 90 and it would not go any further.  I just thought I would ask. I was hoping someone tried it and succeeded. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be tough to push anything semi-rigid through plumbing because plumbing uses tight 90 degree elbows -- not like the long-sweep type used for electrical conduit.

If the flow is not completely stopped then here are a few ideas.

You might have some luck getting some string through the pipe by letting it be carried in the flow of air from a vacuum or flow of water. It may help to tie a small object to the string (a small plastic bag is a common choice) so that the string experiences more drag and is pulled along better in the flow.

If you can get a string though you might be able to use the string to help pull the camera through. It's still going to be tricky to get around the elbows, particularly if the pipe is smaller in diameter.

Underground conduit systems are sometimes tested by feeding a "mandrel" through the pipe. This verifies the pipe is the correct size, is not crimped, etc. You might be able to inspect your piping with a mandrel instead of a camera. A small plastic ball, a piece of wood, etc could serve. Make it half the size of the pipe and find out whether it passes through. Attach a string marked with lengths like a measuring tape to the mandrel so that if it hits an obstruction you'll know how far along the path that occurred. Also, if it becomes wedged and cannot be pulled back out by the string, you'll know where to go digging to extract it.. :-(